# Are javascript chart library customizable or compatible with JavaFX

Tags: java, javascript, d3.js, javafx, topology

I was wondering if typical javascript topology chart libraries can be easily customized to perform some action when I hover or click on the node object? The libraries I'm currently considering are D3.js, chartjs, and sigma.js and the actions could include calling a Java method through JavaFX. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you thinking you can freely mix Java and Javascript?

Answer (score 6):

JavaScript visualization libraries may be integrated with JavaFX via [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) and [it's associated Java<->JavaScript bridge technology](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm).

A sample of such integration is this [JavaFX application which embed a jQuery DatePicker](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1422815).  OK, so a datepicker is not a chart library, but the general integration principle is the same.

Patrick Martin's [Dex project](http://www.javainc.com/projects/dex/) integrates JavaFX (with Groovy) and JavaScript based visualization libraries such as [D3.js](http://d3js.org/), so this proves that integration with D3 can occur (though I don't think Patrick makes available the source for the Dex engine which would allow you to see how he does this).

Note that [JavaFX includes a native charting library](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/jfxpub-charts.htm).  It's charts tend to be traditional business charts such as line charts, pie charts, etc. rather than vizualization of a [mathematical graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29).